# Is this mod detectable by servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Is the minecraft mod "too many items" detectable by servers, is it even client side?

Comment: You can't give yourself infinite items without op on a server using TMI if that's what you're intending to do...

Comment: Thank you that's basically what I wanted to know, but what about just a couple not infinite?

Comment: @user61346 Unionhawk didn't mean giving yourself the special "infinite" items, he meant infinitely giving yourself any items at all.

Comment: Infinite is any number.

Comment: @Paralytic Any *real* number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TMI, NEI, Inventory Tweaks, and other mods that add inventory management and recipe viewers work on servers just fine, and they're not detectable. The major caveat is that any feature that gives you items and blocks simply won't work, because getting items is handle by the server and not the client.

Displaying recipes, showing chunk borders and mob spawning locations, rearranging your inventory are all things that can be done just by the client, so those features generally work. Do note that there *are* plugins that watch your inventory for "too fast" actions though, so using any sorting features of client-side mods (TMI doesn't, but there are others that do) can be detected, if the server operator cares enough.

Comment: Note that plugins like NoCheat keep a tab on inventory actions, and cancel it once it happens too quickly. Autosorting etc become impossible in those cases.

Comment: @Dykam Oh, that's good to know!